# How to vectorize a nested loops in octave?

Tags: octave

I need to speed up my function and I am looking for an efficient way to calculate this two loops below.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
  for i=1:n
    for j=1:m
      ig = i + (j-1)*n;
      coord(ig,1) = i;
      coord(ig,2) = j;
    end
  end

  for j=1:m
    for i=1:n-1
      k = (j-1)*(n-1) + i;
      conec(k,1) = (j-1)*n + i;
      conec(k,2) = (j-1)*n + i+1;
      C(k,1) = CH;
    end
  end

   for k=1:nc
     p = conec(k,1);
     q = conec(k,2);
     aux = [C(k) -C(k) ; -C(k) C(k)];
     A([p q],[p q]) =  A([p q],[p q]) + aux;
   end
```

Comment: I have some problems understanding your code. `coord` is written in the first loop but never read again, are these three loops related? That `C(k,1) = CH;` line looks really odd, aren't you setting the whole array to the same value CH? Please provide [mcve] which we can actually run, meaning all variables are initialized (probably with some random data of the right size). Vectorization is not always the best option to improve the performance. From your question I am not sure if you considered the basics like preallocation.

Comment: Appologies, this is part of the script and I ended up omitting the other parts. The "coord" is an output and it will be used in another function. CH it was inicialized before in another function as CH = 2.3 + 10*e^(-(x-5)^2); I have other similar loop with CV (= 1.8 + 10*e^(-(x-5)^2)) instead of CH. About the third loop, it belongs to other function and returns A that I forgot to put A = zeros(nv) before the loop.